# 2017 Subaru Legacy Air Intake Removal

Tags: air-intake

I'm trying to remove the grey knob. Sorry, I'm pretty new to cars not sure what that piece is called as I'm trying to clean the throttle body and the air intake is in the way. I tried using various sockets. Please let me know if you can see the image as it's too big for me to upload.

Engine Size is 2.5
Mileage is at 7K

https://imgflip.com/i/4sjqes

[image: added image]

Comment: I've placed the image inline for convenience, but don't see a grey knob. There's a bolt in the center and what looks like a rivet through a flange to the right of that.

Comment: The push rivet on the right? If so pry with flat head screwdriver gently in the grove. May have to wiggle left and right. When it pops up, you can pry the whole thing out. If that's not it, need clarification on where the nob is

Comment: did you mean the plastic box? there is no grey knob on this picture... can you post the full picture? so we know what are you talking about and let us know how to open it maybe?

Comment: fred_dot_u: I don't think I see your image? Yes I'm referring to the "rivet". I think that's what needs to be removed so I can access the air intake.

chris: Thank you. I'll try that route. If that doesn't work I'll need to hire an expert.